# Backbone - Custom events in view events object

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I am trying to figure out why this works:

```
var TestView = Backbone.View.extend({
    views: {},

    initialize: function(){
        this.bind('transistion:complete', this.onPageLoaded);

    },

    onPageLoaded: function(){
        alert("works!");
    }
});

var v = new TestView();
v.trigger('transition:complete');
```

But this does not work:

```
var TestView = Backbone.View.extend({
    views: {},

    events:{
        'transition:complete': 'onPageLoaded'
    },

    onPageLoaded: function(){
        alert("works!");
    }
});

var v = new TestView();
v.trigger('transition:complete');
```

It'd be neater to be able to trigger my custom events from within the view's events object. Is there anyway I can get this to work?

Answer (score 8):

The `events` hash is designated for DOM-events (like click ), whereas the events triggered through `trigger` and bound through `on` are Backbone's internal events. So when you go `v.trigger('eventname')`, the event is not a DOM event, but specific to Backbone.

Read more [here](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents)

Answer (score 6):

Backbone events hash is associated to the DOM not to the View.

Check how to run the trigger into the View element:

```
var TestView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events:{
        'transition:complete': 'onPageLoaded'
    },

    onPageLoaded: function(){
        alert("works!");
    }
});

var v = new TestView();
v.$el.trigger('transition:complete');
```

However if the custom event is not required to be bind to the element, your first code is ok, just replace bind, with on, like this:

```
this.on('transistion:complete', this.onPageLoaded);
```